# Calculate averages over each quarter for each associated value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query in BigQuery. I want to know averages over a quarter. With my current SQL, the values for the period of Q1 for `id1` are the same for `id2`.

This is what I had and the values were good:

```
row|averages|quarter|identifier
-----------------------------
1  | 10     | 1     | id1
2  | 20     | 2     | id1
3  | 30     | 1     | id2
4  | 40     | 2     | id2
```

Here's the SQL I wrote for above structure that gives good values:

```
WITH
  index_cal AS (
  SELECT
    values-01,
    kind,
    EXTRACT (QUARTER  FROM  date) as QUARTER,
    date,
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`,
  geom AS (
  SELECT
    identifier
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table2` )
SELECT
   AVG(values-01) AS averages,
    QUARTER AS quarter,
    geom. identifier as identifier
  FROM
    index_cal as g
INNER JOIN
  geom
ON
  INTERSECTS(g.kind,
    geom. identifier)
GROUP BY
  identifier
  quarter
```

What I wanted was to group values for each quarter per identifier such that each identifier has only 1 associated row:

```
row | averages | quarter | identifier
----------------------------------
1   | 10       | 1       | id1
    | 20       | 2       |
----------------------------------
2   | 30       | 1       | id2
    | 40       | 2       |
----------------------------------
```

To get the desired structured such that id1 only has 1 associated row and likewise for all identifiers, I wrote this SQL query:

```
WITH
  index_cal AS (
  SELECT
    values-01,
    kind,
    EXTRACT (QUARTER  FROM  date) as QUARTER,
    date,
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`,
  geom AS (
  SELECT
    identifier
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table2` )
SELECT
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT AVG(values-01) AS averages,
    QUARTER AS quarter
  FROM
    index_cal
  GROUP BY
    QUARTER ) as INDEX,
  geom. identifier as identifier
FROM
  index_cal AS g
INNER JOIN
  geom
ON
  INTERSECTS(g.kind,
    geom. identifier)
GROUP BY
  identifier
```

On running this query, I get average values for all the identifiers grouped by quarter such that values (eg 15 and 25 in this case) are repeated for all identifiers:

```
row | averages | quarter | identifier
----------------------------------
1   | 15       | 1       | id1
    | 25       | 2       |
----------------------------------
2   | 15       | 1       | id2
    | 25       | 2       |
----------------------------------
2   | 15       | 1       | id3
    | 25       | 2       |
----------------------------------
```

What I wish to answer in the end is the average of `values-01` on a quarterly interval based on `identifier`. Currently they are the same for any the value of `identifier`.

Comment: Hi Pranay. I'm still trying to understand the question. Any way to make a simpler case?

Comment: Hi Felipe, edited my question. I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using ARRAY_AGG on the original query that was giving original values

```
with final_cal as (WITH
  index_cal AS (
  SELECT
    values-01,
    kind,
    EXTRACT (QUARTER  FROM  date) as QUARTER,
    date,
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`,
  geom AS (
  SELECT
    identifier
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table2` )
SELECT
   AVG(values-01) AS averages,
    QUARTER AS quarter,
    geom. identifier as identifier
  FROM
    index_cal as g
INNER JOIN
  geom
ON
  INTERSECTS(g.kind,
    geom. identifier)
GROUP BY
  identifier
  quarter)
SELECT identifier, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(averages, quarter)) from final_cal GROUP BY identifier
```